# Issue in declaring an objective-C method in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to use FCOfflineQueue (a persistent framework for queuing network requests while offline) with my iOS app written in Swift. I am supposed to subclass the `FCOfflineQueue` class and override the following method in my subclass-

```
- (BOOL)executeOperation:(int64_t)opcode userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

In my own queue that I subclassed from `FCOfflineQueue`,  am having trouble declaring this in Swift. I am doing the following-

```
override func executeOperation(opcode: Int64, userInfo: NSDictionary) -> Bool
```

It says- this method does not override any method from its superclass.

If instead I do the following-

```
@objc override func executeOperation(opcode: Int64, userInfo: NSDictionary) -> Bool
```

It says- Overriding method with selector 'executeOperation:userInfo:' has incompatible type '(Int64, NSDictionary) -> Bool'

I thought `int64_t` is equivalent to `Int64` in Swift. Is it something to do with the conversion?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to override like this:

```
override func executeOperation(opcode: Int64, userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

> When you bridge from an NSDictionary object with parameterized types
>   to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type
>   [ObjectType]. If an NSDictionary object does not specify parameterized
>   types, it is bridged to a Swift dictionary of type [NSObject:
>   AnyObject].

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html